# How to compile TypeScript without using any references whatsoever

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, tsd

Forgive me if I misunderstand, but I thought that if I used a `tsconfig.json` file at my project root, then I would no longer need to use any `///<reference path="..." />` tags in order to make my code compile. Am I wrong?

For example, I'm using AngularJS. My `App.ts` file looks something like this:

```
import SomeModule from './whatever/SomeModule';

angular.module('foo', [SomeModule.name]).run(...);
```

My `tsconfig.json` file looks (in part) like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./www/**/*.ts",
        "./typings/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        /* a bunch of files omitted for brevity*/
        "./typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"
    ],
}
```

Notice that I have listed in my files array the path to the angular definition file. Also notice that I have the `compileOnSave` option set to false. Eventually I would like to use Browserify to compile and bundle all the code. But for now I just want to see if I can get it to compile with `tsc`.

But when I run `tsc App.ts`, I get an error that says "Cannot find name 'angular'." How do I make the TypeScript compile use the `angular.d.ts` file when compiling the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `tsc App.ts` won't work because a file is being specified. Follow the instructions from the documentation:

> **Using tsconfig.json**
>
> - By invoking `tsc` with no input files, in which case the compiler searches for the `tsconfig.json` file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.
> - By invoking `tsc` with no input files and a -project (or just -p) command line option that specifies the path of a directory containing a `tsconfig.json` file.
>
> *When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.*
>
> [Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json)

Comment: Read the documentation - wish I had thought of that! :)